# Three JS: glitched textures when trying to set up basic skybox

Tags: three.js

I am trying to set up a basic skybox following the code of a tutorial here:
https://gist.github.com/wwwins/4720489

My console puts out no errors whatsoever, but I get very glitched textures for some reason. Already tried png's, but no difference. It seems to be some kind of rendering error, as the textures rather show fragments of what is / was visible on my screen. Does it have something to do with my browser cache somehow? I have to mention at this point, that my Macbook Pro was blacklisted for WebGL by most browsers and it was not advised to use it. Also I had problems with CORS before, as the server I am hosting this on does not allow for it, if that helps in any way. You can have a look yourself here:

http://sultanscourt.com/wip/

this is how it looks in my Chrome (Version 63.0.3239.84):

[image: Glitched Render]

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: it seems a restart of the computer did the trick for now. Therefore this question might be closed.

Comment: Looks real good in Safari here. What renderer are you using if your device is blacklisted by WebGL? What model is it, and if it has multiple GPUs (integrated / discrete), which one are you using?

Comment: Seconded. Looks fine on my end. Tested on Chrome, Firefox and Edge, Windows 10. Might be due to blacklisting or might be a drivers issue, at least so is my first impression.

Comment: It is a Macbook Pro (produced end of 2011). My model was blocked due to having a Intel HD 3000 graphics card built in. Apparently it does only have a single GPU.